# Why does my jasmine test give a 504 on my ASP.net AWS IIS server but if I hit the page directly it works?

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, iis

Here is the scenario:
I have a server running our QBO platform (Asp.net c# CRM/Workflow management system)
One of the things we do when we load the code into Dev is running Jasmine scripts to ensure code is working as required.

On one of the tests we invariably get a 504 before the load balancer time out setting of 1 minute has occurred.  We have seen this 504 as early as 13 or 14 seconds and as late as 40ish seconds.  If we directly hit the server outside of the load balancer we do not get a 504.  If we stand up a beefier dev box based on the same image (more cpu more memory better bandwidth) we still get a 504 if we use the load balancer.

According to some aws forum research there is a time to live vs the load balancer time out but all documentation points to Apache server not IIS and IIS doesn't have a time out / time to live setting on it or if it does I haven't found it.

Comment: Based only the above it's the _load balancer_ that seems to have an (config) issue. What's not clear is when you mention `IIS`, is IIS (ARR?) your load balancer?

Comment: I am using the classic Load balancer from AWS.

Comment: Then you'll have to change your question since it doesn't seem IIS is the issue - which you have verified by bypassing the LB. It sounds more like a config matter on the LB. Hopefully you'll get better help from devs with AWS experience rather than IIS. The only thing I can think of from the ASP.net application side is if you have client checking/restrictions - re: expecting some specific type of request that the LB doesn't meet for some reason - e.g. HTTPs, infinite redirects, etc.